# I don't know why javascript is not working in the below mentioned code for back to top button for the blog page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-rest-framework

The javascript in the base footer file is not working and that's why the back-to-top button in the base file is not working as expected. the functionality and all is working in the back-to-top button but the button is not visible because through javascript, I am adding a class active but it is not adding in this page but the base file is also linked to another page and there everything is working fine. I am not able to figure it out why it is not working. Below is the main blog file where base-home-footer file is linked to.

```
{% extends 'media/assets/base-media.html' %}
{% load main %}
{% load static %}
<!-- title start -->
{% block title %}Prishni- Our Blog{% endblock title%}
<!-- title end -->
<!-- header start-->
{% block header %}
{% include 'assets/base-home-header.html' %}
{% endblock header %}
<!-- header end -->
<!-- Content Start -->
{% block mediaContent %}
{% load markdownExtras %}
<div class="wrapper _bg4586 _new89" id="main-content" role="main">
    <div class="_215cd2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="course_tabs">
                        <nav>
                            <div class="nav nav-tabs tab_crse justify-content-center">
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href=" {% url 'media:ourBlog' %} ">Blog</a>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title129 mt-35 mb-35">
                        <h1 align="center">Insights, ideas, and stories</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_205ef5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
                    <div class="fcrse_3 mt-50">
                        <ul class="blogleft12">
                            <li>
                                <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
                                    <ul class="category-card">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="category-item1 active">All</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="category-item1">Students</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="category-item1">Instructors</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="category-item1">Ideas & Opinions</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="category-item1">Edututs+ News</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="category-item1">Social Innovation</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <a href="{% getFacebookLink %}">
                                <div aria-label="facebook" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;" class="facebook158" data-href="" onclick="sharingPopup(this);" id="facebook-share">
                                <i style="margin:auto;" class="uil uil-facebook ic45"></i>  </div> </a>
                                <a href="{% getLinkedInLink %}">
                                <div aria-label="linkedIn" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;" class="facebook158" data-href="" onclick="sharingPopup(this);">
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in ic45"></i>
                                </div> </a> 
                                <a href="{% getInstagramLink %}">
                                <div aria-label="instagram" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;" class="facebook158" data-href="" onclick="sharingPopup(this);" >
                                <i class="uil uil-instagram ic45"></i>
                                </div> </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-7">
                    {% for blog in blogs %}
                    <div class="blogbg_1 mt-30">
                        <a href="{% url 'media:singleView' blog.id %}" class="hf_img">
                            <img src=" {{ blog.blog_img.url }} " alt="" />
                            <div class="course-overlay"></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="hs_content">
                            <div class="vdtodt">
                                <span class="vdt14">{{ blog.count }} views</span>
                                <span class="vdt14">{{ blog.pub_date }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <a href=" {% url 'media:singleView' blog.id %} " class="crse14s title900">{{ blog.title }}</a>
                            <p class="blog_des">
                                {{ blog.body | markdown | safe | truncatewords:40 }}
                            </p>
                            <a href=" {% url 'media:singleView' blog.id %} " class="view-blog-link">Read More<i
                                class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-p-pagination">
                {% if blogs.has_other_pages %}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% if blogs.has_previous %}
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ blogs.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                        PREV
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="" aria-label="Previous">
                        PREV
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for i in blogs.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if blogs.number == i %}
                    <li class="page-link active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="page-link"><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if blogs.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ blogs.next_page_number }}">NEXT</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="" aria-label="Next">
                        NEXT
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock mediaContent %}
{% block footer %}
{% include 'assets/base-home-footer.html' %}
{% endblock footer %}
<!-- Footer End -->
```

Below is the base-home-footer file where back-to-top button code is implemented.

```
{% block footer %} {% load main %} {% load static %}
<style>
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

  footer .back-to-top .bttBtn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  footer .back-to-top .bttBtn.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  footer .back-to-top .bttBtn.active:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fa6742;
    border-color: #fa6742;
  }
</style>
<footer
  class="footer mt-30"
  style="position: relative; margin-top: 200px; text-align: center"
>
  <div class="container" style="text-align: right">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="item_f1">
          <a href=" {% url 'main:aboutUs' %} ">About Us</a>
          <a href=" {% url 'media:ourBlog' %} ">Blog</a>
          <!--<a href=" {% url 'media:press' %} ">Press</a>-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="item_f1">
          <a href=" {% url 'main:help' %} ">Help</a>
          <a href=" {% url 'main:helpFAQ' %} ">FAQ</a>
          <a href=" {% url 'main:feedback' %} ">Feedback</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="item_f1">
          <a href=" {% url 'main:career' %} ">Careers</a>
          <a href=" {% url 'main:comingSoon' %} ">Advertise</a>
          <a href=" {% url 'main:contactUs' %} ">Contact Us</a>
          <!-- <a href=" {% url 'legal:termsOfUse' %} ">Copyright Policy</a>
                    <a href=" {% url 'legal:termsOfUse' %} ">Terms of Use</a>
                    <a href=" {% url 'legal:termsOfUse' %} ">Privacy Policy</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="item_f1">
          <div class="edu_social_links">
            <a aria-label="faceBook Page" href="{% getFacebookLink %}"
              ><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i
            ></a>
            <a aria-label="LinkedIn Page" href="{% getLinkedInLink %}"
              ><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i
            ></a>
            <a aria-label="Instagram Page" href="{% getInstagramLink %}"
              ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright-->
  <div class="copyright">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="footer_logo">
            <a href=" {% url 'index' %} ">
              <img
                src=" {% static 'images/sign_logo.svg' %} "
                alt="logo, link to home page"
              />
            </a>
            <span>Copyright © 2021, All Right Reserved Prishni</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="copyright-menu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="{% url 'legal:termsOfUse' %}">Terms</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="{% url 'legal:privacyPolicy' %}">Privacy Policy</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="{% url 'legal:cookiePolicy' %}">Cookies</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End col -->
      </div>
      <!-- End Row -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Copyright Container -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Copyright -->
  <!-- Back to top -->
  <div id="back-to-top" class="back-to-top" onclick="toTop()">
    <div class="btn btn-dark bttBtn" aria-label="Back to Top">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Back to top -->
</footer>
<script>
  function toTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $(".back-to-top").addClass("active");
  }

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 150) {
      $(".bttBtn").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".bttBtn").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
</script>
{% endblock footer %}
```

Comment: Too many code here. Can you make a simple demo in snippet? Maybe you can figure out by yourself while making the demo :)

Comment: actually the problem is in the blog file itself because the base file is also linked to another page and there everything is working absolutely fine. But I am not able to figure it out which part is making the problem.

Comment: actually only the scroll logic function is not working for this file